# libgit2 / pygit2 is there a way to do an update-server-info?

Tags: libgit2, pygit2

I need to prepare a repo for access from an HTTP server.

To do seem it seems I need to run git update-server-info on the repo which updates some files that make it accessible over a dumb HTTP server.

I am using Pygit2 / Libgit2 to create the repo.  Does libgit2 allow me to do a update-server-info or do I need to somehow execute the command line git to do so?

I have searched extensively so if it is available then I'm looking in the wrong places to find how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgit2 does not offer any support for the dumb HTTP protocol, but since this is the server, it wouldn't help much it implemented `update-server-info`.

In order to support the dumb protocol you need to make `git update-server-info` run after every push into the server's repo via one of the hooks which git provides, so you need to be using git for this anyway.